# Contextmenu - disable right click to open it

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contextmenu

I have such xaml code:

```
<Grid x:Name="boardGrid">
    <Grid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu Opacity="0.7" x:Name="menuContext">

        </ContextMenu>
    </Grid.ContextMenu>
</Grid>
```

I generate grid's items in code behind. What I want is to disable context menu opening on right click. I want to open it when certains conditions occur.

This is what I have in .cs file:

- generating Unit's objects and putting them into Grid;

each object has unit.MouseRightButtonUp += unit_MouseRightButton

```
void unit_MouseRightButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (CurrentGame.CurrentPlayer.HasTurn == false) return; 
    .....
    ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;

}
```

So it means that Contextmenu should be open only if condition is fulfilled but it opens anyway.

Answer (score 15):

You can set the attached property `ContextMenuService.IsEnabled` to `false`. Then you can manually popup the ContextMenu.

You must set that property for the GUI element that owns the menu. Setting it for the menu itself will do nothing.

```xml
<Grid x:Name="boardGrid" ContextMenuService.IsEnabled="false">
    <!-- ... -->
</Grid>
```

```cs
void unit_MouseRightButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    if (CurrentGame.CurrentPlayer.HasTurn == false) return; 
    .....
    boardGrid.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
}
```

Comment: or via code using `ContextMenuService.SetIsEnabled(this, false);`

Comment: The `ContextMenuService` is much simpler if your `MenuItem`s have `MenuItem`s of their own; simply doing `ContextMenu.IsOpen = true` leaves any submenus hidden.